# Append data from Ajax after fancybox close callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, fancybox-2

i need to fill a div with certain content from ajax after fancybox close, on parent page

```
<div id="ajax-content-here"></div>
```

So using callback from fancybox Documentation

```
afterClose : function() {
  //Ajax query here values in json format
}
```

Function closes the fancybox fine and im getting in my network check all the required data in json format

```
{value1:1, value2:2, value3:3}
```

But when i attempt to add it to the div container nothing happens

```
$("#ajax-content-here").html( data );
```

Might be a dumb error but i'm a little stuck, any advices?

Comment: are you getting the `data` with `afterClose : function(data) {`?

Comment: @SumanBogati Yes but i'm getting an [object] result, guess its in a different data type. how do i check what im receiving?

Comment: which keyword you are using to response the data like if you used `name` on server side,  then use `data['name']` on client side to get data.

Comment: im getting nothing returned in `function(data)` that's what's causing it

Comment: So that's the problem then, first make sure that the data is returned successfully, then display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a parameter to the callback, and check for the dataType on Ajax

```
afterClose : function() {
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET/POST",
    url: "myURL",
            dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
         // Handler for data Result
    }
    });     
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a parameter to the function :

```
afterClose : function(data) {
  $("#ajax-content-here").html( data );
}
```

I'm not really sure this is the solution because I'm not that familiarized with jQuery